# Issue creating HTMLDocument object

Tags: vba

```
Set html = CreateObject("HTMLDocument")
```

> Run-time error '429'. ActiveX component can't create object

```
Sub GetCurrentGoldPrice()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim gold_price As String
    
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = CreateObject("HTMLDocument")
    
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", "https://goldprice.org/", False
    xmlhttp.send
    
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
    gold_price = html.querySelector("#gold-price").innerText
    
    MsgBox "The current gold price is " & gold_price
    
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    Set html = N
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to collect data from the Web it to use Power Query integrated in Excel.
Goto 'Data' tab, and Press 'Get Data' - select 'From Web' - enter the URL. Then start your selection of objects possible to pick the data from. You need to find tables on the web page or Json objects that actually contain data. In your case you can pick the URL https://goldprice.org/spot-gold.html from this web page table. Then clean up the dataset by replacing unwanted text and the Close and load to retur your table values to Excel. The 'Advanced Editor' will show something like this DAX expression to perform the query. Then you can refresh whenever you want.

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://goldprice.org/spot-gold.html")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"", type text}, {"Product", type text}, {"Details", type any}, {"Best Price", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"", "Details"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns","As Low As","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Best Price"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","Shop Now","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Best Price"})
in
    #"Replaced Value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue here is that the MSHTML object library is no longer supported by Microsoft. There are many questions on Stack Overflow where issues have arisen in existing code as a result.

Here is one way to get the required information using Excel VBA and Selenium

```
Sub sbGetCurrentGoldPrice()
    Dim sFilename As String
    Dim gold_price As String
    Dim we As WebElement
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    driver.Start ("edge")
    driver.Get ("https://goldprice.org/")
    Set we = driver.FindElementByClass("gp-slogan-infobar")   ' <h2 class="gp-slogan-infobar">
    gold_price = we.Text ' WHERE THE WORLD CHECKS THE GOLD PRICE - today $1,923.7
    MsgBox "The current gold price is " & gold_price
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.Quit
End Sub
Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub
```